# Core Data Reload Database

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, core-data

I need Core Data to reload the store after I overwrite it with a database that I generated and downloaded from a web server. I am having some trouble with getting the database reloaded. I have tried calling reset on all of the contexts and parent context along with setting the persistent store coordinator, managed object context, and managed object model to nil.

Comment: How are you overwriting the data?  Are you deleting existing objects in the existing persistent store then writing your new objects?  Or are you somehow overwriting the store file itself?

Comment: Overwriting the store itself. I gzip decompress a file download and overwrite the sqlite store

Comment: Ah, I've never done this; but there a [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9782588/replace-a-sqlite-database-at-runtime) that might be helpful.

Comment: I'm having trouble using [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3374633/replacing-core-data-sqlite-file-while-app-is-running-data-does-not-update) and the link you posted. I get an error when trying to remove the store saying it doesn't exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem. I was setting the app delegate's properties to nil but wasn't setting the managed object context of the root view controller to nil and reinitializing it.